# Good HTTP request analyzer for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, http

On Windows, I use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for analyzing HTTP requests and replies. Is there a similar tool for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wireshark is available for download in the Synaptic Package Manager in Ubuntu.

Comment: I totally forgot it was cross-platform :)